# how to get flat binary code address on bare metal?

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, disassembly, bare-metal

I have the source code of an assembly file that I want to disassemble after converting it to binary so I can set breakpoints in correct locations.

I've tried using `objdump` with the following command (I'm using an ORG statement, that's why I use `--adjust-vma`)

```
objdump -Mintel,i386 -b binary --adjust-vma=0x0500 -D foo.o -m i386 | less
```

which works to some extent, but it confuses the instructions, for example in my source code I have

```
    pop bx
    inc bx  ; bx is used in the internal copy_sector_byte loop
    cmp cx, 512
    jne .copy_sector_byte  
    pop bx
```

but it's translated to

```
 5a9:   5b                      pop    ebx
 5aa:   43                      inc    ebx
 5ab:   81 f9 00 02 75 e7       cmp    ecx,0xe7750200
 5b1:   5b                      pop    ebx
```

note that the `75 e7` is the binary code on the `jne` instruction.

can I tell `objectdump` to use the source file I have in some way (or using another program)? What are your suggestions?

I'm new to assembly. Thank you

Comment: You appear to be disassembling 16-bit code as 32-bit code. You should be able to just use `objdump -Mintel,i8086 -b binary --adjust-vma=0x0500 -D foo.o | less` . `-Mi8086` will disassemble as 16-bit code.

Comment: Or use `ndisasm` or ask your assembler for a listing.

Comment: @MichaelPetch my code has both 32 and 16 bit code, any suggestions?

Comment: Which assembler are you using, and what are you debugging with? Are you debugging with BOCHs? GDB/QEMU, something else?

Comment: @shakram02 I think then `objdump` isn't much of a help.

Comment: @Jester the listing did the job, can you add this as an answer so I can mark it?  please mention that it's necessary to add the ORG address manually

Comment: @MichaelPetch, sorry I didn't mention those; nasm and gdb

Comment: So when you say GDB for debugging you are remote connecting to something like QEMU that runs the OS?

Comment: yes, exactly. I'm remote connecting to QEMU

Comment: Personally I would be generating an ELF version of the kernel file and a binary version. The ELF version can contain the debug information while the binary version will be what is executed.

Comment: I'd stop using `binary` as the output type of a linker script. Just have it generate ELF executable and then convert the ELF executable to a binary file with `objcopy`. The binary file runs on the remote machine, the ELF file is used in the debugger. The ELF file can be used by the debugger for symbolic information which is the easiest thing to debug with. I will say that GDB and QEMU are tricky to debug 16-bit real mode code with since GDB has no real understanding of segment:offset addressing in real mode.

Comment: I'll try that now, thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get NASM to make a "listing" when it assembles: `nasm -l foo.lst foo.asm` (with the default flat-binary output mode, and default output filename of `foo`).  Or have it write the listing to stdout with `nasm -l /dev/stdout foo.asm  | less` if you just want to look at it on the fly.

But unfortunately the output doesn't respect the `org` directive, it's still relative to the image base:

```
     1                                  org 0x7c00
     2                                  
     3 00000000 31C0                    xor ax,ax
     4 00000002 8ED8                    mov ds, ax
     5                                  
     6 00000004 686869                  push "hi"
     7 00000007 C706[0D00]7879          mov word [var], 'xy'
     8                                  
     9 0000000D 68656C6C6F              var: db "hello"
```

---

Or as @MichaelPetch suggested in comments:

> Personally I would be **generating an ELF version of the kernel file and a binary version.** The ELF version can contain the debug information while the binary version will be what is executed.
>
> I'd stop `using` binary as the output type of a linker script. Just have it generate ELF executable and then convert the ELF executable to a binary file with `objcopy`. The binary file runs on the remote machine, the ELF file is used in the debugger.
>
> The ELF file can be used by the debugger for symbolic information which is the easiest thing to debug with.
>
> I will say that GDB and QEMU are tricky to debug 16-bit real mode code with since GDB has no real understanding of segment:offset addressing in real mode.

**BOCHS has a built-in debugger which *does* understand segmentation**, and has built-in commands for parsing the IDT and GDT instead of just dumping raw bytes.

Michael has recommended BOCHS in the past for debugging bootloaders that switch to protected and/or long mode.